# play video with UIimageview

Tags: ios, video, uiimageview

You can play video in a UIImageView?? for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, an image view is for images. You can have a set of animated images but you can't play an actual video.

---

You could use a `MPMoviePlayerController` to play a true video and add its view in place of the image view.

Comment: as I can get that effect ???

Comment: For simple animations that you don't want to play with controls like a movie you can look into 'UIImageView startAnimating' like with this tutorial:     http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/